# Spark to AWS ElasticSearch Service

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, spark-streaming, amazon-emr, aws-elasticsearch

I am running spark on my local machine. I have Elastic Search up and running in AWS-ElasticSearch service. I am trying to follow the documentation specified here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html

Version of Elasticsearch-spark that I am using is,

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark-20_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is how my SparkConf looks like:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName(properties.getProperty("app.name"))
                .set("es.nodes", "search-**********.us-west-1.es.amazonaws.com")
                .set("es.port","443")
                .set("es.http.timeout", "5m")
                .set("es.nodes.wan.only", "true");

# Call the method to send logs to ES, assume stringResults to a JavaDStream<Map<String, Object>> object
ElasticSearchManager.sendToEs(stringResults);
```

This is how I am trying to store the data in ElasticSearch

```
import static org.elasticsearch.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaEsSparkStreaming.saveToEs;

public class ElasticSearchManager {

    public static void sendToEs(JavaDStream<Map<String, Object>> javaDStream) {
        ZonedDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        saveToEs(javaDStream,
                dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd")));

    }
}
```

This is the error I get

```
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverClusterInfo(InitializationUtils.java:340)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$.doSaveToEs(EsSpark.scala:104)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.streaming.EsSparkStreaming$$anonfun$doSaveToEs$1.apply(EsSparkStreaming.scala:71)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.streaming.EsSparkStreaming$$anonfun$doSaveToEs$1.apply(EsSparkStreaming.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.$anonfun$foreachRDD$2(DStream.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.$anonfun$foreachRDD$2$adapted(DStream.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.$anonfun$generateJob$2(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.$anonfun$generateJob$1(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.$anonfun$run$1(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: [GET] on [] failed; server[search-************.us-west-1.es.amazonaws.com:443] returned [400|Bad Request:]
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.checkResponse(RestClient.java:477)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:434)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:428)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:388)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:392)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:168)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.mainInfo(RestClient.java:745)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverClusterInfo(InitializationUtils.java:330)
    ... 19 more
```

I tried to debug as to what's the issue. And, this is what I found in package `org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.java  in line 745`

```
Map<String, Object> result = get("", null);
```

Not sure why they would set the URI in the get method to empty string. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I had the same problem. Your post helped me solved my issue. One difference I had was the "es.nodes" field; adding "https://" in front of the endpoint worked for me.